# Button Click Action in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a game and right now and I need the buttons to have an action attached to the them when one is clicked but I keep getting an error saying "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
 ClassBody" there is not an error of a missing "}" however so there must be a problem with the code itself.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Menu extends Window implements ActionListener
{

  Button start = new Button("Start Game:");
  Button quit = new Button("Quit");
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start Game: "))
{
  System.out.print("Button one clicked");
}
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Quit"))
{
  System.out.print("Button two clicked");
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `onActionPerformed` is not in a class block:

```
public class Menu extends Window implements ActionListener
{ //Class block starts

  Button start = new Button("Start Game:");
  Button quit = new Button("Quit");
} //Class block ends

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
....
```

---

All ethods of a class must be inside the block of the class:

```
public class Menu extends Window implements ActionListener {

    Button start = new Button("Start Game:");
    Button quit = new Button("Quit");

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start Game: ")) {
            System.out.print("Button one clicked");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Quit")) {
            System.out.print("Button two clicked");
        }

    }
}
```

Also, you might have to decide if you are going to use AWT widgets (`java.awt.*`) or Swing Components (`javax.swing.*`).

For instance, when you say `Button button = new Button();`, its an AWT widget. In order to use the Swing one, you must `JButton jButton = new JButton();`.

Comment: Okay thank you. I switched to JButton, but is there any reason or thing I have to add to get the button clicks to show up in the console so you can see which button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on the button.

Add this inside your class

```
start.addActionListener(this);
quit.addActionListener(this);
```

Also you have to move the `actionPerformed` function inside class body.
Your class will look like

```
public class Menu extends Window implements ActionListener
{

  Button start = new Button("Start Game:");
  Button quit = new Button("Quit");
  start.addActionListener(this);
  quit.addActionListener(this);

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start Game: "))
  {
    System.out.print("Button one clicked");
  }
  else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Quit"))
  {
    System.out.print("Button two clicked");
  }    
}
}
```